# If Ann(n)=P where P is a prime ideal, then there exists $a \in R-P$ such that $an=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring and $N$ is a $R$-module.
If it is the case the $P=Ann(n)$ for some $n\in N$ where $P$ is a prime ideal. Then there exists $a \in R-P $ such that $an=0$.

Hi all,

I am trying to prove this statement, but I have having a few problems. Partly because I am not sure how to start and I think the statement is false.

Since, $R/P \cong Rn$ as R-modules. Wouldn't it be the case that $an=0$ if only if $a \in P$?

Comment: Where's the problem come from?

Comment: @rschwieb The problem came from abstract dummit and foot abstract algebra. Page 670 question 34.

Comment: I tried to look up the problem in the archive.org copy, and I found several problems which looked similar with yours but were not recognizable as yours. Perhaps it is a different revision than yours.  Can you type the original problem as it appears in your text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that something is wrong.

There can't exist an $a\notin Ann_R(n)=\{r\in R\mid rn=0\}$ such that $an=0$.